# Visualforce outputlink to network location switches slash

Tags: visualforce

I need to create a link that takes the user to a network drive. I built a vf page that will sit in a Dashboard component. When I hover over the link and click it where I had set backslashes in code they are being swtitched to forward-slashes. is there a way to force the format of an Outputlink?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputText value="For your Varicent Statements, click on the URL into your browser" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLink target="_blank"     value="https://icm.ibmcloud.com">Here</apex:outputLink>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputText value="For Manual Statements please go to your virtual folder" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="\\\W2fs2\support\CorpSales\Sales\">Here</apex:outputLink>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>    
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

When the link displays on the page it looks like this: file:///W2fs2/npdsupport/CorpSales/Sales/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: \ is backslash, / is slash (a.k.a. forward-slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't "force" the `\\<server>\<path>\<file>` syntax. Visualforce isn't modifying your links. Your *browser* is changing the URI to a format specified by [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.10). See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/) written by a Microsoft employee that explains how URIs should be. You should be using "`file://///<server-name>/<path>/<file>`".

Comment: that's exactly what I need and couldn't find. Thanks.

Comment: @DanWooding It's five forward slashes at the beginning. I just updated my answer.

Comment: It still trims the forwards slashes to // no matter how many I put in. I added file: and removed file: and got the same results...

Comment: @DanWooding It'll depend on the browser you're using. Most browsers today, if not all, purposefully mangle links to private resources on public sites. You might not have any choice in the matter, other than to set up IIS to access those resources.

Comment: yeah working with our IT team that was what was happening. It's too much effort for this use case to start changing security settings for all the users so I ended up displaying as text and they can copy and paste. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯